# Is there a formal class theory that suffices to formalize the basic notions of category theory?

Tags: logic, category-theory, foundations, formal-systems

Is there a formal class theory that suffices to formalize the basic notions of category theory? I think the usual formalizations of class theory like Neumann-Bernays-Gödel or Morse-Kelley don't suffice (for the latter, see the thread [Morse-Kelley and category theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953652/morse-kelley-and-category-theory)) to formalize the basic notions of category theory. For example, a category is a tuple consisting of a (possibly proper) class of objects and a (possibly proper) class of morphisms and a composition operation. Also one wants to consider class-functions to formalize the notion of a functor.

Comment: How about ZFC plus an assumption that there are arbitrarily large inaccessible cardinals? From what I hear this appears to be a common setting for category theory these days; it implies that everything you could reasonably be interested in will take place inside some [Grothendieck universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, this is a good solution. But I am somehow interested in how one can formalize the "proper class vs. set" approach to category theory.

Comment: More important is how to formalize ideas such as categories of categories. I think they are called $1$-categories ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Yes, that's also interesting: Is there a formal theory which formalizes the notion of "collection of classes"?

Comment: Yeah, and what about "conglomerates of collections of classes" ?

Comment: MK does suffice to formalize much of category theory. I had left a comment to that effect, which I've turned into an answer now at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953652/morse-kelley-and-category-theory

Comment: @user376483: it would be possible to formalize "collections of classes" directly, by adding a new type to the language and adding axioms to form collections of classes. Then one could add "collections of collections of classes", etc. But this gets clunky very quickly, because we have to keep adding types, and because it isn't clear how far into the transfinite we can go. So there is another option: just start with a model of ZFC with an inaccessible $k$. Then view $V_k$ as the "sets", $V_{k+1}$ as the "classes", $V_{k+2}$ as "collections of classes", etc. This has basically the same effect.

Comment: @CarlMummert: So in Morse-Kelley set theory, one can define the notion of an n-tuple which may contain members that are classes? Than the notion of category and the notion of functor can be formalized in Morse-Kelley, right?

Comment: @user376483: please see my full answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1960702/630 . The summary is that one can use the language to simulate having finite tuples of classes, and this is good enough to be able to formalize categories, quantify over them, and quantify over functors. It would not allow you to form a "category of all categories", however.

Comment: @CarlMummert: But could you answer my question? So in Morse-Kelley set theory, one can define the notion of an n-tuple which may contain members that are classes? Than the notion of category and the notion of functor can be formalized in Morse-Kelley, right?

Comment: The focus on $n$-tuples of classes is misplaced, as I explain in my answer to the other questions. There is no need for $n$-tuples of classes to formalize category theory. Once we move past that, yes, the notion of category and the notion of functor can be formalized in MK, as I explain in the other answer.

Comment: @CarlMummert: If one wants a category $C=(Ob(C), Mor(C), \circ)$, couldn't we define this category in Morse-Kelley as a 3-tuple, for example $(Ob(C)\times \{0\})\cup (Mor(C)\times\{1\})\cup (\circ\times\{2\})$?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the final part of my answer, but that is not the same class, in set theory, as the tuple $(\text{Ob}(C), \text{Mor}(C), \circ)$ which would be $\{ (0, \text{Ob}(C)), (1, \text{Mor}(C)), (2, \circ)\}$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: By "that is not the same class, in set theory, as the tuple (Ob(C),Mor(C),∘)" you mean that this encoding of class-tuples is not using the usual Kuratowski encoding of sets?

Comment: No, I mean that it is not a $3$-tuple at all, because a $3$-tuple should be a function with domain $\{0,1,2\}$ while the set/class you have formed is not a function. It is also true that the set/class you have formed is not obtained by applying the Kuratowski pairing operation twice. But this is not vital to formalizing category theory because there is no reason we have to represent the three parts of the category as a tuple, we can just pass three variables around in our formulas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46536/discussion-between-carl-mummert-and-user376483).